Blazor two-way binding with readonly data types
I am trying to take advantage of Entity Framework Core 8's new complex properties feature for my webapp. I've made my Address model, which used to be a full entity with its own table, into a readonly record struct that exists as a complex property of several other models, for example Customer.
I have a Blazor component meant to be included in create/edit forms called AddressSubForm. It contains all the form fields necessary for an Address. The problem is, where before I could simply @bind-Address="Customer.Address", now that Address is readonly it won't be able to change the subproperties of the Address to reflect user input. That in itself isn't a problem, it's not hard or expensive to create a new Address using the with syntax for creating new records by modifying an old one. But Blazor or Entity Framework (it's not clear to me which) is having trouble tracking the changes to Address now, and it's saving null for all the Address columns to the database.
My most recent attempt looks like this:
@using System.Linq.Expressions
<FormItem Field="Address">
    <Template>
        <label for="Address" class="k-label k-form-label">Address</label>
        <div id="Address" class="k-form-field-wrap">
            <p>
                <label>Street Address</label>
                <TelerikTextBox @bind-Value="Street1"
                                OnChange="async value => { Address = Address with { Street1 = (string)value }; await AddressChanged.InvokeAsync(); }" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Street Address (line 2)</label>
                <TelerikTextBox @bind-Value="Street2"
                                OnChange="async value => { Address = Address with { Street2 = (string)value }; await AddressChanged.InvokeAsync(); }" />
            </p>
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>
    </Template>
</FormItem>

@code {
    [Parameter] public Address Address { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Address> AddressChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<Address>> AddressExpression { get; set; }

    private string Street1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private string Street2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    // ...

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Street1 = Address.Street1;
        Street2 = Address.Street2;
        // ...
    }
}

How can I change this component so that it properly keeps track of any changes made to the Address complex property and allows it to be saved to the database?

There's no EF code here. Besides, read-only and two-way binding suggest a misunderstanding. You want two-way binding if you intend to update both your ViewModel and your database entities. Which means they need to be editable. Are you trying to apply some "best practices"  ?

The OnChange callbacks are wrong too. There's no reason to call AddressChanged like this. Blazor data binding generates those events itself. The fact you had to write so much complicated code is a very strong indication that you're doing things wrong.

(it's not clear to me which You're creating a completely new Address object every time a property changes, one that neither EF nor Blazor know anything about. If automatic data binding is used Blazor itself will raise the -Changed event when Address = Address with{} assigns the new object to the Address property. EF knows nothing about it though. You'll have to attach this new object to the DbContext again

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm aware I'm doing things wrong, if I weren't doing things wrong then I wouldn't be having this problem. This was simply the last attempt of many to get this to work, and when my code started looking like this was when I knew I had to ask. I have heard in the past that sometimes explicitly invoking the event callback can solve issues with two-way binding. Obviously it did not work in this case.

I was able to solve this problem by passing a Func to this component that sets the Address property to the new value. Because of this, I no longer need two-way binding.
In AddressSubForm.razor:
<FormItem Field="Address">
    <Template>
        <label for="Address" class="k-label k-form-label">Address</label>
        <div id="Address" class="k-form-field-wrap">
            <p>
                <label>Street Address</label>
                <TelerikTextBox @bind-Value="Street1"
                                OnChange="value => Address = SetAddress(Address with { Street1 = (string)value })" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Street Address (line 2)</label>
                <TelerikTextBox @bind-Value="Street2"
                                OnChange="value => Address = SetAddress(Address with { Street2 = (string)value })" />
            </p>
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>
    </Template>
</FormItem>

@code {
    [Parameter] public Address Address { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter] public Func<Address, Address> SetAddress { get; set; }

    private string Street1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private string Street2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    // ...

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Street1 = Address.Street1;
        Street2 = Address.Street2;
        ...
    }
}

In AddCustomer.razor:
<AddressSubForm Address="Customer.Address"
                SetAddress="address => Customer.Address = address"/> 


There are several approaches you can take to this rather complex topic.
This answer is based on code from a recent article of mine. It implements the concept of a record edit context within sub-form.  The sub-form uses a subsidary EditContext.
It also includes proper edit state tracking and form locking.
First the data objects.  Person is a standard DTO type object.  Address is a record value object.  TrackState is part of state tracking.
public class Person
{
    [TrackState] public string? Name { get; set; }
    // Tracking handled by the Sub-form
    public Address? Address { get; set; }
}

public record Address(string Town, string PostCode);

Next the sub-form.  It takes the bind provided Address value object and builds an AddressEditContext to manage the Address object editing.  There's some extensive inline commenting to explain what's happening.
@using System.Linq.Expressions

<EditForm EditContext="_editContext">
    <label class="form-label">Town</label>
    <InputText class="form-control mb-2"
               @bind-Value=_recordEditContext.Town
               @bind-Value:after="OnPossibleChange" />
    <label class="form-label">PostCode</label>
    <InputText class="form-control mb-2"
               @bind-Value=_recordEditContext.PostCode
               @bind-Value:after="OnPossibleChange" />
</EditForm>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext ParentEditContext { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public Address? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Address> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<Address>> ValueExpression { get; set; } = default!;

    private Address _address = default!;
    private EditContext _editContext = default!;
    private AddressEditContext _recordEditContext = default!;
    private Address? _previousState;

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        // Quick and dirty Exception checking
        // Fix in production code
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Value);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(ParentEditContext);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(ValueExpression);

        // If _address is null, then this is the first render event
        // build out the state objects from the provided address
        if (_address is null)
        {
            _address = Value;
            _recordEditContext = new(_address);
            _previousState = _address;
            _editContext = new(_recordEditContext);
        }

        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    private async Task OnPossibleChange()
    {
        // Get the current state from the RecordEditContext
        var state = _recordEditContext.AsRecord;

        // Get the field identifier for the Address field
        var fi = FieldIdentifier.Create(ValueExpression);

        // If the state has changed:
        //  Update the state, notify the parent edit context and raise the ValueChanged callback
        if (state != _previousState)
        {
            _previousState = state;
            ParentEditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fi);
            await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(state);
        }

        // Check if the address has reverted to the original state
        // if so clear the Address from the EditContext modified list
        if (!_recordEditContext.IsDirty)
            ParentEditContext.MarkAsUnmodified(fi);
    }

    private class AddressEditContext
    {
        private Address _baseRecord;

        public string Town { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }

        public AddressEditContext(Address address)
        {
            _baseRecord = address;
            Town = address.Town ?? string.Empty;
            PostCode = address.PostCode ?? string.Empty;
        }

        public Address AsRecord
            => new(this.Town, this.PostCode);

        public bool IsDirty => _baseRecord != this.AsRecord;
    }
}

Finally the Demo page to edit the Person.  I've added functionality to track the state properly using BlazrEditStateTracker and lock the form using NavigationLock.
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Composite Object Editor Demo</h1>

<EditForm EditContext="_editContext">
    <BlazrEditStateTracker/>

    <label class="form-label">Name</label>
    <InputText class="form-control mb-2"
               @bind-Value=_model.Name />

    <AddressEditor @bind-Value="_model.Address" />

    <div class="text-end mb-2">
        <button hidden="@_isDirty" class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="this.Exit">Exit</button>
        <button hidden="@_isClean" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="this.ExitWithoutSaving">Exit without Saving</button>
        <button disabled="@_isClean" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

<NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation="_isDirty" OnBeforeInternalNavigation="this.CheckNavigationAllowed" />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Name = @_model.Name</pre>
    <pre>Town = @_model.Address?.Town</pre>
    <pre>Postcode = @_model.Address?.PostCode</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private Person _model = new() { Name="Fred", Address = new("Hacconby", "PE10 OUX") };
    private EditContext _editContext = default!;
    private bool _isDirty => _editContext.IsModified();
    private bool _isClean => !_isDirty;
    private bool _exit;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _editContext = new(_model);
    }

    private void ExitWithoutSaving()
    {
        _exit = true;
        this.NavManager.NavigateTo("/Counter");
    }

    private void Exit()
    {
        this.NavManager.NavigateTo("/Counter");
    }

    private void CheckNavigationAllowed(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        if (_isDirty && !_exit)
            context.PreventNavigation();

            _exit = false;
    }
}

Here's the project file to show the two packages:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Blazr.EditStateTracker" Version="1.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

The Blazr.EditStateTracker Repo is here.

